# c++ Modify a String to contain the string repr. of an integer

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm a scientist, not a programmer, please have mercy.

I want to create files in a loop, incrementing an integer in the filename:

```
file01.txt

file02.txt
....

file10.txt
```

.
.
.

I have two problems.
This is the kernel of what I've tried:

```
char fn[] = "file00.txt";
int i = 1;
fn[5] = i;
```

This results in an error "expected expression"
I though that should work becauase "charcters are integers"

```
fn[5] = (char)i;
```

results in the same error.
And I've tried a few other things.  After that I have to figure out what happens when i>9 and I have two digits.  Suggestions desperately needed.

(I've spent *hours* trying to understand strings, char, array, etc.  Just when I think I got it, a new problem pops up.)

Comment: You cant use fn[5]= (char) i  because i can a number larger then 9. so what happend if i is 20, you cant convert it to char

Comment: Characters aren't integers, they are numeric values representing a character in a particular encoding scheme, so there is a difference between `char(0)` and `char('0')`. If your char is holding an ASCII value, the value 32 represents space (`' '`), the value 48 represents `'0'`. You can write `fn[5] = '0' + i` but that only covers one digit for you.

Comment: The error message sounds like a compiler error, but you didn't show the whole thing so there's no way to tell. The code you show here shouldn't have generated such a compile error.

Comment: Do you *have* to have the leading zeros, or would `file1.txt` be acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is

```
for(int file_index = 0; file_index < max_file_index; ++file_index) {
    // Render your file name:
    std::ostringstream file_name;
    file_name << "file" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << file_index << ".txt";
    // Create the file using file_name.str() 
    // (or file_name.str().c_str() for pre c++11 standards)
    std::ofstream outfile(file_name.str());
    // ...
}
```

---

I've got absolutely no clue why you are bothering to change the

```
char fn[] = "file00.txt";
```

in 1st place.

If you try to do so, the conversion should take character values into account like

```
fn[5] = i + '0';
       // ^^^^^^
```

and will give you more complications for values of `i` greater than `9`.

Comment: There's no undefined behavior from modifying that array.

Comment: It would be undefined behavior if you did `char *fn = "file00.txt";`, but it's not undefined when you declare an array.

Comment: @Barmar Ah well, I see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way, C style:

```
int i = 0; // ...
char fn[16];
sprintf(fn, "file%02d.txt", i);
```

Comment: Sometimes the old C way is best, IMHO. This is so much simpler than the `stringstream` and string concatenation ways in the other answers.

Comment: Not a problem so long as  `i < 10000000`After that, welcome to buffer overflow land! Easily solved with a quick test, and if you're generating that many files... Eeeeyipe!

Comment: @user4581301 A directory with 10 million files? I think buffer overflow would be the least of his problems.

Comment: With you on that, @Barmar, but been bit doing this before. The files were being deleted after consumption, but the number kept going up and after a few weeks, Blammo. Best to do the test.

Comment: @user4581301: if OP had written "file000000000.txt" in the question, I'd probably have made the effort of increasing buffer size and testing i...

Comment: I wish I had thought of this.  I won't be able to try it for several days.  I'll report back what happens.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written will not do what you expect. You are changing the 6th character(ie, the second 0) to a character represented by the number. Take a look at an [ASCII table](http://ascii-code.com/) and you will see that a 0 integer does not correspond to a '0' character; in fact, it will correspond to a null character, which is taken to indicate the end-of-string in C-style strings.

Even if you convert the integer values to proper ASCII values, you will still only modify the second zero. So 10 would result in "file0:.txt" **not** "file10.txt". `:` comes after `9`.

I strongly advise not doing this the C way, which you are trying to. Use `std::string` for safety and simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( )
{
    std::string name = "file";
    std::string extension = ".txt";
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        std::string fullName;

        if( i < 10 )
           fullName = name + '0' + std::to_string( i ) + extension;
        else
           fullName = name + std::to_string( i ) + extension;

        std::cout << fullName << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output (with omissions):

```
file00.txt
file01.txt
...
file09.txt
file10.txt
file11.txt
...
file98.txt
file99.txt
```

Note: [`to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) requires C++11. It also is broken on some g++ builds on Windows. This can be done with [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), but is less elegant.

Comment: using std::string was my first thought, and it was easy to implement.  But I have to send this into a library function that's looking for a char*, and it barfs if give it  string.c_str() which produces something different, evidently.

Comment: @garyp Is it trying to write to it? `c_str()` is const char*, so it would not match functions either intending to write the value, or simply not allowing for a const. You might be able to get around that with `const_cast`, but using that is generally a bad idea. Still might be preferable to dealing with c strings.